# Add a JSON variable to typescript class with getter setter

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript class where I have a few getter and setter methods for few variables. example:

```
export class TestService {
    private created: boolean;

        public getCreated(): boolean {
        return this.created;
    }

    public setCreated(created: boolean): void {
        this.created= created;
    }

}
```

I would like to add one more variable to this class and add a getter setter for this. However this variable is not a simple string/boolean primitive but needs to be some sort of JSON that would could have its own properties (say color, size, shape) that can be set, I do not want 3 extra variables for these 3 propeties with their corresponding getter setter methods, but just one JSON that would hold 3 different properties. What would be the best way to do this? preferably without having to create a new class outside this file

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a data transfer format.

Read about TypeScript interfaces, define one, and add a field whose type is that interface to your service.

You should avoid such getters and setters in TypeScript. This is a Java idiom, but TypeScript can define getters and setters for regular properties if needed.

Your service should be reduced to

```
export interface Foo {
  bar: string;
  baz: number;
  wiz: boolean;
}

export class TestService {
  created: boolean;
  foo: Foo; 
}
```

If, later, you realize that you need to intercept every change to the `created` property, then you can change to the following code, without having to change anything to the client code of this service:

```
export class TestService {
  private _created: boolean;
  foo: Foo; 

  get created(): boolean {
    return this._created;
  }

  set created(c: boolean) {
    console.log('setting created...');
    this._created = c;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an interface to match these properties:

```
interface Item {
  color: string;
  size: string;
  shape: string;
}
```

Whether or not you use this in a separate file is up to you, but then you could use it:

```
private item: Item;
public getItem(): Item {
  return this.item;
}
public setItem(item: Item) {
  this.item = item;
}
```

You can also do an inline type object literal:

```
private item: { color: string, size: string, name: string };
```

However this is a lot more verbose and more prone to errors since if you update the type in one spot you would potentially have to update it everywhere.

Side not: you could use [TypeScript Accessors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) for getter/setter if you wanted.